# Does `docker build` run a new container every time I use FROM in a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, docker-build

Is it correct to say that whenever I use the command `FROM` in a Dockerfile, the `docker build` process creates a new container where the subsequent commands run?

If not, can you please provide a more accurate description?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Keep in mind that the only way to create a docker image (from another image) is to start the base image, make the changes required and persist the container's state into a docker image.

Comment: It'd be more correct to say that every `RUN` command executes in a new container.

Comment: Thanks @ turing85 and @david-maze . Would either of you be interested in expanding a little bit and include references to source in an answer so that I can accept it? 